# Java Formatting Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to get the current date and format it however i am getting an invalid month of 59. Under is the code

**Code**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date todayDate = new Date();

String formatDate = df.format(todayDate);
```

Output is 2013-59-07

Comment: Did 59 not give it away?

Comment: lol yes i decided to change it after i post the question now came on and saw it was really that. Thanks

Comment: Eh, give the people their points :)

Comment: SO is making me wait lol i will accept one as soon as i can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `"MM"` for month. `"mm"` is for minutes.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 4):

You have used `mm` which means minutes.  Use capital `MM` instead.

You can find all date and time pattern symbols on the [`SimpleDateFormat` Javadoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capital `MM` and not `mm`. Lower case 'mm' is for minutes and not for months.

So, your code would be :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Month is retrieved by `MM`, not `mm`.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Refer to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) JavaDoc:

> M     Month in year

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String dt = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Use  MM instead of mm.